# Delete file if number in filename less than xxxx

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I have thousands files in format randomstring_XXXXXXXX.jpg where 'xxx' is unixtime (1388415305). Now I need to delete all files older than some (unixtime) date.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl solution (untested):

```
perl -e 'unlink grep { ($d) = /_([0-9]+)\.jpg/ and $d < XXXXXX } glob "*_*.jpg"'
```